# Entity Framework & WPF Application Design Guidance

Tags: entity-framework

Entity Framework Layer Guidance

I'm in the design stage of a WPF business application.  The first stage of this application will be a WPF/Desktop application.  Later iterations may include a browser based mini version.

I envision creating a dll or 2 that contain the domain model & dbcontext that all applications(Desktop or Browser) will use.

My intention is to ride or die with EF.  I'm not worried about using DI/Repository patterns etc for flexibility.  The benefits of using them don't outweigh the added complexity in my opinion for this project.  My plan is to use a model, and a derived dbcontext.

Having said that, I'm looking for input on where to put certain types of method code.

An example will hopefully make my question more clear:

Let's say I have the following two entities..

Entity: Employee

Entity: PermissionToken

Inside of these two entities I have a ManyToMany relationship resulting in me creating another entity for the relationship:
EmployeesPermissionTokens

For clarity, the PermissionToken Entity's Primary Key is an Enum representing the permission..

In the application, lets say the current user is Administering Employees and wants to grant a permission to an Employee.

In the app, I could certainly code this as:

```
var e = dbcontext.Employees.Find(1);
var pt = new PermissionToken
{
    PermissionID=PermissionTypeEnum.DELETEUSER";
    ...
}

e.PermissionTokens.Add(pt)
```

But it seems to me that it would be more convenient to wrap that code in a method so that one line of code could perform those actions from whatever application chooses to do so.  Where would a method like that live in all of this?

I've thought about adding a static method to the EF Entity:

In The employee class:

```
public static void GrantPermission(PermissionToken token)
{
    e.PermissionTokens.Add(token);
}
```

Going further, what would be really convenient for the app would be the ability to write a line like this:

```
Permissions.GrantToEmployee(EmployeeID employeeId, PermissionTypeEnum 
permissionId);
```

Of course that means that the method would have to be able to access the DbContext to grab the Employee Object and the PermissionObject by ID to do its work.  I really want to avoid my entities knowing about/calling DbContext because I feel long term the entities get stuffed full of dbcontext code which in my opinion shouldn't even be in the Model classes.

So Where would a method like this go?

My gut tells me to put these sorts of code in my derived DbContext since in order to do these sorts of things, the method is going to need access to a DbContext anyway.

Does this make sense, or am I missing something?  I hate to write oodles of code and then figure out 3 months later that I went down the wrong road to start with.  Where should these types of methods live?  I know there is probably a purist answer to this, but I'm looking for a clean, real world solution.

Comment: You move data access into a new project. Make a new class to provide these methods to your main application. You might call this class an EmployeeService. Then you might have `employeeService.Grant(employeeId, permissionId)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are making a good decision to not abstract EF behind a repository.

With the EF Context you have a class supporting the  Unit Of Work pattern which is handling your data access needs.No need to wrap it up in repository.

However this does not mean you should call the Context directly from your controller or viewmodel.

You could indeed just extend the DbContext however I suggest to use services to mediate between your controllers/view models and your dbcontext.

If e.g. in your controller you are  handling a user request (e.g. the user has clicked a button) then your controller should call a service to archive what ever "Use Case" is behind the button.

In your case this could be a PermissionService, the PermissionService would be the storage for all operations concerning permission.

```
public class PermissionService
{

     PermissionService(DbContext context)
     {
     }

     public bool AddPermission(Employee e, PermissionType type) { }
     public bool RemovePermission(Employee e, PermissionType type) {}
}
```

Your service ofcourse needs access to the DbContext.

It makes sense to use DI here and register the DbContext with a DI Container.

Thus the context will be injected into all your services. This is pretty straight forward and I do not see any extra complexity here.

However, if you don't want to do this you can simply new up up the Db Context inside your services. Of course this is harder / impossible to mock for testing.